# VBA Code to Create a Multi-Dimensional Array of Weeks Worked for Workers

Tags: arrays, vba

Long time reader, first time posting.

I am trying to create an array that contains a list of workers along with each week that a worker has listed in the source table. For example, the source data looks essentially like this:

```
| Worker # | Week |
| 1        | 1/1  |
| 1        | 1/8  |
| 1        | 1/15 |
| 2        | 1/1  |
| 3        | 1/8  |
| 3        | 1/15 |
```

And I would want the resulting array to be:

```
|  1  | 1/1  | 1/8  | 1/15 |
|  2  | 1/1  |
|  3  | 1/8  | 1/15 |
```

For context, I am trying to create a multi-dimensional array of weeks each worker has submitted a timesheet for so that I can compare it to a multi-dimensional array of weeks when each worker SHOULD have worked. The goal is to identify missing timesheets. If there's a more elegant solution than using arrays I'm open to hearing it. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome on your first post. Please add the vba code for what you have tried and explain what didn't work. Also, wouldn't a pivottable sort this? For both datasets  (actual & expected) there would need to be a row present with all weeks in e.g. a dummy row

Comment: You could also just do with formulas by adding a helper id column which concatenates worker and week and do a lookup/match from expected table to actual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to get the row and column numbers and place the values in an array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim DicR As Object 'Dictionary
    Dim DicC As Object 'Dictionary
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim s As String
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) 'data Sheet
    Set toWs = Sheets(2) 'Result Sheet
    
    Set DicR = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DicC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") ' New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    vDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 100)
    
    For i = 2 To r
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        If DicC.Exists(s) Then
            DicC(s) = DicC(s) + 1
        Else
            n = n + 1
            DicR.Add s, n 'row index
            DicC.Add s, 2 'column index
        End If
        vR(n, 1) = s
        vR(DicR(s), DicC(s)) = vDB(i, 2)
    Next i
    
    c = WorksheetFunction.Max(DicC.Items)
    
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To r, 1 To c)
    With toWs
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(r, c) = vR
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also uses a dictionary.

```
Sub TransposeWeeks()
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim arrData()
Dim arrWeeks()
Dim dic As Object
Dim cnt As Long
Dim idx As Long
Dim ky As Variant

    arrData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    
    Set rngDst = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For idx = LBound(arrData, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)
        ky = arrData(idx, 1)
        
        If dic.Exists(ky) Then
            arrWeeks = dic(ky)
            cnt = UBound(arrWeeks) + 1
        Else
            cnt = 1
        End If
           
        ReDim Preserve arrWeeks(1 To cnt)
        
        arrWeeks(cnt) = arrData(idx, 2)
        dic(ky) = arrWeeks
    Next idx
    
    For Each ky In dic.keys
        rngDst = ky
        arrWeeks = dic(ky)
        rngDst.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(arrWeeks)).Value = arrWeeks
        Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
    Next ky
    
End Sub
```